# SSIS --The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property

Tags: ssis, checkpoint

I have package that I have been testing for the last 8 months. 
Today when I deployed the package on the client machine, it gave the following error:

> MainContainer:Error: The result of the expression
>   "@[$Project::FilePath]+ @[System::PackageName]+".xml"" on property
>   "\Package.Properties[CheckpointFileName]" cannot be written to the
>   property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the
>   property.

@[$Project::FilePath] contains the file path. In this case the value is: C:\Verfication_Reports\

@[System::PackageName]:MainContainer

The package executes successfully but it generates the above error in the SSISDB. This property contains the path of checkpoint file. Please help.

Comment: I ran into same problem and found this post useful http://bisherryli.com/tag/ssis-best-practices/

Comment: Thank you EvZ.I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but anyway. 
make sure the path also exists in the client's file system.

Comment: This would make a mediocre comment, but is almost a no-go for an answer ...